# diskusage how to use in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, sysinternals

I am very new to powershell and writing a script which will go to each computer in windows domain and get the size of a user profile. I have tried below on a powershell script

```
$profileDir = "\\$computerName\c$\users\userProfile"
$fullProfile = (Get-ChildItem $profileDir -recurse -force | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
```

But on some computer it gives below error. The problem seems that some directories on the profile have a long path and `get-ChildItem` fails

```
Get-ChildItem : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully
qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name mu
st be less than 248 characters.
At C:\scripts\powershell\profiles.ps1:56 char:30
+ $fullProfile = (Get-ChildItem <<<<  $profileDir -recurse -force | Measure-Obj
ect -property length -sum)
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (\\computerName...nt.IE5\RQT4K4JU:St
   ring) [Get-ChildItem], PathTooLongException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChil
   dItemCommand
##########################################################################################################################
```

At this point I tried using `du.exe` (diskusage) from SysInternals which works fine but I don't know how to take the output of `du` into a variable. I have below on my script

```
$dirSize = .\du.exe -c c:\temp |convertFrom-csv | select-object DirectorySize
write-host $dirSize
```

The output is

```
PS C:\scripts\powershell> .\profiles.ps1

@{DirectorySize=661531}
```

What I want the output to be like

```
PS C:\scripts\powershell> .\profiles.ps1

661531
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a hashtable. You need to reference the item in that hashtable to get it's value. Instead of:

```
Write-Host $dirSize
```

Try:

```
$dirSize['DirectorySize']
```

Comment: Thanks but I get below error PS C:\scripts\powershell> .\profiles.ps1
Unable to index into an object of type System.Management.Automation.PSObject.
At C:\scripts\powershell\profiles.ps1:7 char:21
+ write-host $dirSize[ <<<< 'DirectorySize']
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (DirectorySize:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotIndex

Comment: OK, try $dirsize.directorysize

Comment: Your hashtable comment gave me a clue. I tried $dirSize.DirectorySize and the output is now as expected. PS C:\scripts\powershell> .\profiles.ps1
661531    Thank you again!